# net.thucydides.core.pages.WrongPageError: The page object class looks dodgy:

Tags: java, cucumber, serenity-bdd

Getting below exception while assigning a list of the map to another list. I am trying to use Datatable defined in my cucumber step to another scenario in my feature file. To access it I have defined list outside the method but while running my program `WrongPageError` and `XXX.pages.ProductPage looks dodgy:` exception.

```
net.thucydides.core.pages.WrongPageError: The page object class webapplication.ecom.contactlenses.pages.ProductPage looks dodgy:
Failed to instantiate page (java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class)

    at net.thucydides.core.pages.Pages.thisPageObjectLooksDodgy(Pages.java:295)
    at net.thucydides.core.pages.Pages.getCurrentPageOfType(Pages.java:223)
    at net.thucydides.core.pages.Pages.getPage(Pages.java:90)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.PageObjectDependencyInjector.instantiatePageObjectIfNotAssigned(PageObjectDependencyInjector.java:55)
```

Please refer below code:

```
public class ProductPage()
{
@FindBy(xpath = "")
public WebElementFacade productNameHeader;

@FindBy(xpath = "")
public WebElementFacade productPriceHeader;


public List<Map<String, String>> productdetails;

public void addproduct(DataTable product) {


    List<Map<String, String>> myproduct = product.asMaps(String.class, String.class);
    productdetails=myproduct;

    }

public List<Map<String, String>> getProductInfo(DataTable product) {

    return productdetails;
}
```

}

I have tried to define a static list of an element so like static variables, I can access this list of elements but still no luck.If I removed or commented out reference of `public List<Map<String, String>> productdetails;` then program works fine.

Please suggest if I am doing anything wrong or missing something.